# How to write the sum of function inside LaTeX?

Tags: macros, pstricks, asymptote, recursion

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
    \psset{xunit=1,yunit=2,linewidth=1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=500](-.5,-1.5)(12,2)
    %
    \def\numerator#1{\fpeval{(-1)^(#1)/(fact(#1)*fact(#1))}}
    \def\function#1{(x/2)^(2*#1)}
    \def\hihihaha#1{\numerator#1*\function#1}
    %%
    \psclip{\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none](-.5,-1)(11,1.2)}
    \psset{algebraic}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue!50!orange]{0}{3}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}} % =2
    \psplot[linecolor=red!50!orange]{0}{5}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}} % =4
    \psplot[linecolor=blue!50!red]{0}{6}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}} %=6
    \psplot[linecolor=blue!50!yellow]{0}{8}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}} %=8
    \psplot[linecolor=pink!50!orange]{0}{10}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}} %=10
    \psplot[linecolor=pink!50!cyan]{0}{12}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}+\hihihaha{6}} %=12
    \psplot[linecolor=green!50!orange]{0}{14}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}+\hihihaha{6}+\hihihaha{7}} %=14
    \psplot[linecolor=pink!50!red]{0}{16}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}+\hihihaha{6}+\hihihaha{7}+\hihihaha{8}} %=16
    \psplot[linecolor=blue!50!green]{0}{18}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}+\hihihaha{6}+\hihihaha{7}+\hihihaha{8}+\hihihaha{9}} %=18
    \psplot[linecolor=cyan!50]{0}{18}{\hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}+\hihihaha{3}+\hihihaha{4}+\hihihaha{5}+\hihihaha{6}+\hihihaha{7}+\hihihaha{8}+\hihihaha{9}+\fpeval{1/(fact(10)*fact(10))}*x^20/\fpeval{2^20}} %=20
    \endpsclip
    \psBessel{0}{0}{10}%
    \psaxes[showorigin=false,arrowinset=.2,arrowsize=.2,%
    xsubticks=2,xsubticksize=1,ticksize=0 7pt,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-1.5)(11,2)
    \rput(6,.75){$\displaystyle
        J_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k+1)}
        $}%
    \uput[-90](3,-1){$n=2$}
    \uput[-90](4.2,-1){$n=6$}
    \uput[-90](6,-1){$n=10$}
    \uput[-90](7.7,-1){$n=14$}
    \uput[-90](9.2,-1){$n=18$}
    \uput[-90](10,-.2){$J_0(x)$}
    %%%
    \uput[90](4,1.2){$n=4$}
    \uput[90](5.3,1.2){$n=8$}
    \uput[90](6.8,1.2){$n=12$}
    \uput[90](8.4,1.2){$n=16$}
    \uput[90](10,1.2){$n=20$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

1. How to rewrite `\hihihaha` by recursion? (It mean that I would to it is more shorter)
2. Of course, how to write the `sum` of function inside LaTeX? (With any your suggestions) It mean that --with k=1, LaTeX print `the content of \hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}`,with k=2, LaTeX print `the content of \hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2}`, ... !

Comment: What do you mean by *the sum of function*? Of which function?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, `J_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k+1)` :)

Comment: I don't think pstricks can calculate  sums of series.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, sorry, my idea is to print `\stuff`, example, with k=1, I have \hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}, with k=2, I have \hihihaha{0}+\hihihaha{1}+\hihihaha{2},`...` . I would to LaTeX will print `the content of series automatically` ...

Comment: The Ti*k*Z library `math` allows you to define recursions, see the example on p. 694 of pgfmanual v3.1.4. There are already a few examples on this site using this for plots. Of course, plain LaTeX does allow you to define things recursively, so there should be no problem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat :-) ,instead of researching pgfmanual, please to give me a standard answer... I know you can with more your explanations.

Comment: Try `\foreach \X in {0,...,10}
 {\ifnum\X=0
 \xdef\mysum{\expandafter\hihihaha{\X}}%
 \else
 \xdef\mysum{\mysum+\expandafter\hihihaha{\X}}%
 \fi}
 \typeout{\mysum}` (I cannot test at the moment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it - using nested `\multido`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-func,xfp}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1,yunit=2,linewidth=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=500](-.5,-1.5)(12,2)

  \psclip{\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none](-.5,-1)(11,1.2)}

    \psset{algebraic}

    \colorlet{linecol1}{blue!50!orange}
    \colorlet{linecol2}{red!50!orange}
    \colorlet{linecol3}{blue!50!red}
    \colorlet{linecol4}{blue!50!yellow}
    \colorlet{linecol5}{pink!50!orange}
    \colorlet{linecol6}{pink!50!cyan}
    \colorlet{linecol7}{green!50!orange}
    \colorlet{linecol8}{pink!50!red}
    \colorlet{linecol9}{blue!50!green}
    \colorlet{linecol10}{cyan!50}

    \multido{\iA=2+1,\iL=3+2,\iC=1+1}{10}{%
      \def\x{0 }%
      \multido{\iB=0+1}{\iA}{%
        \xdef\x{\x + \fpeval{(-1)^(\iB) / (fact(\iB) * fact(\iB))} * x^\inteval{2 * \iB} / \fpeval{2^(2 * \iB)}}
      }%
      \psplot[linecolor=linecol\iC]{0}{\iL}{\x}
    }

  \endpsclip

  \psBessel{0}{0}{10}%
  \psaxes[showorigin=false,arrowinset=.2,arrowsize=.2,%
  xsubticks=2,xsubticksize=1,ticksize=0 7pt,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-1.5)(11,2)

  \rput(6,.75){$\displaystyle
    J_0(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2 k}}{k! \Gamma(k + 1)}
    $}%
  \uput[-90](3,-1){$n = 2$}
  \uput[-90](4.2,-1){$n = 6$}
  \uput[-90](6,-1){$n = 10$}
  \uput[-90](7.7,-1){$n = 14$}
  \uput[-90](9.2,-1){$n = 18$}
  \uput[-90](10,-.2){$J_0(x)$}
  %%%
  \uput[90](4,1.2){$n = 4$}
  \uput[90](5.3,1.2){$n = 8$}
  \uput[90](6.8,1.2){$n = 12$}
  \uput[90](8.4,1.2){$n = 16$}
  \uput[90](10,1.2){$n = 20$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The variable definitions include:

- `\iA` (`i`nteger from 2,...,11): Number of elements in each function
- `\iL` (`i`nteger from 3,...,21): x-max according to which to evaluate the function
- `\iC` (`i`nteger from 1,...,10): Used to extract the line colours `linecol\iC` (could also just have used `\iA` and shifted the colours `linecolX`)
- `\iB` (`i`nteger from 0,...,`\iA`): Internal sequence of terms expanded to match the specified function

The outer `\multido` initialized `\x` and `\psplot`s the function `\x`. The inner `\multido` constructs `\x` by progressively adding a `\iB`-th term.
Within each iteration of `\multido`, `\x` has a term added to it

Comment: Your answer is accepted. Very good for \multido. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but why does \def\x{0 }% have the white space?

Comment: @justonly: You don't need it. I just wanted the compilation of `\x` to have spaces between the operators and operands. Before `\psplot[..]{.}{.}{\x}`, add `\show\x` to see what `\x` looks like (with and without the space).

Answer (score 12):

An alternative using `Asymptote`, 
with automatically calculated endpoints of the graphs :

```
//
// sumfunc.asy
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph; import math; import palette;
size(14cm,6cm,IgnoreAspect);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");
real xmin=0,xmax=10.2, ymin=-1,ymax=1;
real dxmin=0, dxmax=0.22, dymin=dxmax, dymax=dxmax;
xaxis(xmin-dxmin,xmax+dxmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),above=true);
yaxis(ymin-dymin,ymax+dymax,LeftTicks (Step=1,step=0.5),above=true);

pair f(real x){return (x,Jn(0,x));}
pair fn(real x, real n){
  real a=1, s=1;
  for(int k=1;k<=n;++k){ 
    a*=-(x/2)^2/k^2; s+=a;
  }
  return (x,s);
}
typedef pair pairFreal(real);
pairFreal Fn(int n){return new pair(real x){return fn(x,n);};}
real[] yClip={-1.1,1.1};
guide[] gfn;
for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
  guide g=graph(Fn(i+1),xmin,xmax);
  g=firstcut(g,(xmin, yClip[i%2])--(xmax, yClip[i%2])).before;
  gfn.push(g);
}

pen[] fnPen=Gradient(gfn.length+1,lightblue,darkblue);

guide gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax);
draw(gf,fnPen[fnPen.length-1]+1.2bp);
label("$J_0(x)$",relpoint(gf,1),plain.S);
for(int i=gfn.length-1;i>=0;--i){ 
  draw(gfn[i],fnPen[i]+0.7bp);
  label("$n=$"+string((i+1)*2),relpoint(gfn[i],1),(0,-(-1)^i));
}

label("$J_0(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}"+ 
"\frac{(-x^2)^k}{4^k(k!)^2}$",(5,0.6),UnFill);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, many new things about Asymptote for me.

Comment: What a lovely, pleasant color scheme.

Comment: @wchargin: Just a simple gradient between the two colors. 
You might like to check out 
[web tool for guidance in choosing choropleth map color schemes](http://colorbrewer2.org/)
and 
[Colorbrewer2 color schemes for asymptote](https://github.com/blatts/asy-colorbrewer).

Answer (score 6):

This is my comment from above. It shows that for large enough `n` the Bessel function gets well approximated. The sum gets accumulated in a loop, which also stores the intermediate sums in macros that can be plotted in another loop. (In principle one loop would be sufficient to do everything but the question is how to define the sum in LaTeX.) Luckily pstricks nowadays loads `pgffor`, so I can just loop over your colors without any additional efforts.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
    \psset{xunit=1,yunit=2,linewidth=1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=500](-.5,-1.5)(13,2)
    %
    \def\numerator#1{\fpeval{(-1)^(#1)/(fact(#1)*fact(#1))}}
    \def\function#1{(x/2)^(2*#1)}
    \def\hihihaha#1{\numerator#1*\function#1}
    \foreach \X in {0,...,20}
    {\ifnum\X=0
    \xdef\mysum{\expandafter\hihihaha{\X}}%
    \else
    \ifodd\X
    \xdef\mysum{\mysum\expandafter\hihihaha{\X}}%
    \else
    \xdef\mysum{\mysum+\expandafter\hihihaha{\X}}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\xdef\csname mysum\romannumeral\X\endcsname{\mysum}
    \fi}
    \typeout{\mysumi}
    %%
    \psclip{\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none](-.5,-1)(11,1.2)}
    \psset{algebraic}
    \foreach \Color [count=\X]in {blue!50!orange, %=2
    red!50!orange, %=4
    blue!50!red,%=6
    blue!50!yellow,%=8
    pink!50!orange,%=10
    pink!50!cyan,%=12
    green!50!orange,%=14
    pink!50!red,%=16
    blue!50!green,%=18
    cyan!50}%=20
    {\expandafter\psplot[linecolor=\Color]{0}{18}{\csname mysum\romannumeral\X\endcsname}}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{18}{\mysum} %=20
    \endpsclip
    \psBessel{0}{0}{10}%
    \psaxes[showorigin=false,arrowinset=.2,arrowsize=.2,%
    xsubticks=2,xsubticksize=1,ticksize=0 7pt,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-1.5)(11,2)
    \rput(6,.75){$\displaystyle
        J_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k+1)}
        $}%
    \uput[-90](3,-1){$n=2$}
    \uput[-90](4.2,-1){$n=6$}
    \uput[-90](6,-1){$n=10$}
    \uput[-90](7.7,-1){$n=14$}
    \uput[-90](9.2,-1){$n=18$}
    \uput[0](10.8,-0.2){$n=40$}
    \uput[-90](10,-.2){$J_0(x)$}
    %%%
    \uput[90](4,1.2){$n=4$}
    \uput[90](5.3,1.2){$n=8$}
    \uput[90](6.8,1.2){$n=12$}
    \uput[90](8.4,1.2){$n=16$}
    \uput[90](10,1.2){$n=20$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know you will. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func,pst-math,amsmath,xfp}
\makeatletter
\def\myBessel{\@ifnextchar[{\myBessel@i}{\myBessel@i[]}}
\def\myBessel@i[#1]#2{{%%%  #2 = kmax
  \pst@killglue
  \psset{plotpoints=500,#1}%
  \psplot{0}{\inteval{#2+2}}{% #2=kmax
    /Sum 1 def
    1 1 #2 { /k exch def
     -1 k exp x 2 div k dup add exp mul % -1^k (x/2)^(2k)
     k 1 add GAMMA k tx@AddMathFunc begin ! end mul  % denominator
     Div  
     Sum add /Sum exch def
    } for
    Sum
  }%
}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=2}
\begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=500](-.5,-1.5)(12,2)
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-.5,-1)(11,1.2)}
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=10+10}{10}{\myBessel[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red!\iB]{\iA}}
\psBessel{0}{0}{10}%
\endpsclip
\psaxes[showorigin=false,arrowinset=.2,arrowsize=.2,%
    xsubticks=2,xsubticksize=1,ticksize=0 7pt,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-1.5)(11,2)
\rput(6,.75){$\displaystyle
    J_0(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k+1)}$}%
\uput[-90](3,-1){$n=2$}   \uput[-90](4.2,-1){$n=6$}
\uput[-90](6,-1){$n=10$}  \uput[-90](7.7,-1){$n=14$}
\uput[-90](9.2,-1){$n=18$}\uput[-90](10,-.2){$J_0(x)$}
    %%%
\uput[90](4,1.2){$n=4$}   \uput[90](5.3,1.2){$n=8$}
\uput[90](6.8,1.2){$n=12$}\uput[90](8.4,1.2){$n=16$}
\uput[90](10,1.2){$n=20$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your PostScript code with new several things. :-) ...

Comment: Off topic, assume that `\psplot...{a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+...+an*x^n}`, in PSTricks, the biggest value of `n` is ?

Comment: Try it by yourself ...