# How to plot bessel function in tikz on overleaf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I tried using some existing code, but that seem to not work in overleaf.

Also it was recommended to run this in : `pdflatex -shell-escape` but I did not find this option in the compilers.

**code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, height=0.5*\textwidth, xlabel=$x$]
    \addplot+[id=parable,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt]
    gnuplot{besj0(x)} node[pin=95:{$J_0(x)$}]{};
    \addplot+[id=parable,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt, color=red]
    gnuplot{besj1(x)} node[pin=130:{$J_1(x)$}]{};
    \addplot+[id=parable2,domain=0:20, samples=500, mark=none, width=2pt, color=black]
    gnuplot{2*1/x*besj1(x)-besj0(x)} node[pin=-140:{$J_2(x)$}]{};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you never need shell-escape at overleaf. They have gnuplot examples  eg https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-gnuplot-plus-tikz/qhrvjqtctxxw

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, thanks for the help. Can you provide some example where bessel function is used.

Comment: have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513405/how-to-write-the-sum-of-function-inside-latex/513419#513419

Comment: and here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342808/plot-bessel-functions